# synergy won't compile -- undefined reference to `pthread_xxxx

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake

When following the [build instructions for Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/wiki/Compiling#Unix.2C_Linux.2C_Mac_OS_X), I get the following errors.

**Is there an already-developed solution to get Synergy to build?**
If not, how do I get Synergy to compile on Ubuntu 13.10?

```
../../../../../lib/libarch.a(CArchMultithreadPosix.o): In function `CArchMultithreadPosix::newMutex()':
CArchMultithreadPosix.cpp:(.text+0x319): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
../../../../../lib/libarch.a(CArchMultithreadPosix.o): In function `CArchMultithreadPosix::raiseSignal(IArchMultithread::ESignal)':
CArchMultithreadPosix.cpp:(.text+0x43b): undefined reference to `pthread_kill'
../../../../../lib/libarch.a(CArchMultithreadPosix.o): In function `CArchMultithreadPosix::threadSignalHandler(void*)':
CArchMultithreadPosix.cpp:(.text+0x490): undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
../../../../../lib/libarch.a(CArchMultithreadPosix.o): In function `CArchMultithreadPosix::closeThread(CArchThreadImpl*)':
CArchMultithreadPosix.cpp:(.text+0x62b): undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
../../../../../lib/libarch.a(CArchMultithreadPosix.o): In function `CArchMultithreadPosix::newThread(void* (*)(void*), void*)':
CArchMultithreadPosix.cpp:(.text+0x8e6): undefined reference to `pthread_sigmask'
CArchMultithreadPosix.cpp:(.text+0x90f): undefined reference to `pthread_sigmask'
CArchMultithreadPosix.cpp:(.text+0x935): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
CArchMultithreadPosix.cpp:(.text+0x9a4): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
../../../../../lib/libarch.a(CArchMultithreadPosix.o): In function `CArchMultithreadPosix::CArchMultithreadPosix()':
CArchMultithreadPosix.cpp:(.text+0xe11): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
CArchMultithreadPosix.cpp:(.text+0xf05): undefined reference to `pthread_sigmask'
CArchMultithreadPosix.cpp:(.text+0xf26): undefined reference to `pthread_sigmask'
../../../../../lib/libarch.a(CArchMultithreadPosix.o): In function `CArchMultithreadPosix::startSignalHandler()':
CArchMultithreadPosix.cpp:(.text+0x10a8): undefined reference to `pthread_sigmask'
CArchMultithreadPosix.cpp:(.text+0x10cd): undefined reference to `pthread_sigmask'
CArchMultithreadPosix.cpp:(.text+0x1104): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
../../../../../lib/libarch.a(CArchMultithreadPosix.o): In function `CArchMultithreadPosix::cancelThread(CArchThreadImpl*)':
CArchMultithreadPosix.cpp:(.text+0x5e3): undefined reference to `pthread_kill'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../../bin/synergyd] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/cmd/synergyd/CMakeFiles/synergyd.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Going back to: /usr/local/src/synergy-1.4.15-Source
Error: make failed: 512
```

Comment: Is synergy not available in the Ubuntu repositories? Why are you trying to compile it yourselves instead of installing it from the repos?

Comment: Though Synergy is available in the repos, I was hoping to contribute to the project's improvement. Before I may do this, I need to be able to compile it. I was hoping for assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SOLUTION: manually change the order of the contents of */synergy-1.4.15-Source/src/cmd/synergyd/CMakeFiles/synergyd.dir/link.txt* to *[put -lpthread contents last](http://synergy-foss.org/osqa/questions/3384/compile-problem-undefined-reference-to-pthread_xxxx)*.

Answer (score 2):

You'd rather edit the `CMakelists.txt` file to add `pthread` at the end of the `target_link_libraries` command.

You may also add `link_libraries(pthread)`.